# CSS3 z-index issue

Tags: html, css, z-index

Sorry for such a "dummy" question but I really couldn't find a solution.

I have illustrated the situation graphically:

[image]

Inside the `container`, there are **TWO** siblings (`RED <div>`and `BLUE <div>`). **Both** have `position: absolute;`

**RED** has `z-index:1;`
**BLUE** has `z-index:2;`

**RED**'s child (**GREEN**) has `position:relative;` and `z-index:99;`

### I want to make GREEN to be upper than **BLUE**

Thank you!

**UPDATE 1.**  Here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/yn9z7/

Comment: Could you try getting this on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to solve that is in the article linked by sudhAnsu63 :

> New stacking contexts can be formed on an element in one of three ways:
>
> When an element is the root element of a document (the  element)
>
> When an element has a position value other than static and a z-index value other than auto
>
> When an element has an opacity value less than 1

But the interpretation is just the **opposite**. To set the blue element between the red and the green, the red one can not generate a stacking context. It is generating an stacking context because of the second rule; it has position absolute an z-index different from auto.

So, the solution is:

```
#red{
    z-index:auto;
}
```

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/yn9z7/2/)

Answer (score 1):

This won't work since Red's z-index is lower than blue. z-index only works with elements with a common root element.

Check out the **Stacking Contexts** part in [this article](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/)

Answer (score 1):

Here the Blue div and the Red div is the direct child of container div. z-Index will not work exactly.

try changing the opacity of blue div to 0.99;

```
.bluediv {
  opacity: .99;
}
```

http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/
http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/

Comment: The hack with opacity didn't work. Thank you for the articles.

Answer (score 0):

yeah, this is not possible because child elements inherit the z-index of the parent. so it does not make sense to give the green div a z-index of 99 because it's z-index is only valid inside the parent (red div). 
So if you give a container a certain z-index lets say 20, the z-indexing inside this container starts again from 0. this is a good thing because otherwise we had to give all children a z-index of minimal 21 or they won't be visible. 
the first container on a web page is the body tag, you can stack all its children with the z-index property starting from layer 0 (z-index 0). just like the body tag every child has its own z-index "system" unrelated to higher elements in the DOM. so the z-indexing starts over from 0 inside a parent container with its own defined z-index.